# How can I extract text after the first colon in a string with two of them?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string as `Test Data: Before the Data : "The War"`. I need to extract the string after the first colon. So the output should be:

> Before the Data : "The War"

Comment: Nit: `:` is a colon, a semicolon is `;`.

Comment: Which part(s) is/are the string?

Comment: Overspecifying something would not give you the best result. This is known as X/Y problem. Are you sure you need to use regular expression to do that?

Comment: This question does not show any effort

Answer (score 3):

### Regex Match with Keep Operator

You can use:

```
/:\s*\K.*/
```

#### \K Defined

The `\K` operator isn't well-documented in Ruby, but you can find it explained in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

> There is a special form of this construct, called \K , which causes the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the \K and not include it in $& . This effectively provides variable-length look-behind. ...For various reasons \K may be significantly more efficient than the equivalent (?<=...) construct, and it is especially useful in situations where you want to efficiently remove something following something else in a string.

#### Practical Example

Consider the following:

```
string = %q{Test Data: Before the Data : "The War"}.match(/:\s*\K.*/).to_s
#=> "Before the Data : \"The War\""
```

This will match the first colon followed by optional whitespace, discard the match up to that point, and then capture the rest of the string as [MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/MatchData.html). Invoking [#to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/MatchData.html#method-i-to_s) on the MatchData object returns the match as a [String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) for assignment or output.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 'Test Data: Before the Data : "The War"'
p a[/: (.+)/, 1] #=> "Before the Data : \"The War\""
```

I don't understand why some of the solutions are so complicated here, the regex should be pretty simple: First find the first colon and then capture everything after it.

Comment: As why it is tagged regex, they're not needed for the OP problem at all, it just sounds a restrictive question on a broader problem, so giving clues about regex as the OP seems interested in them lead to overcomplicating them.

Answer (score 2):

### Use String Methods

As one example, the [String#partition](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-partition) method will let you specify a pattern as either a string or a regular expression. Since you essentially just want to discard the first half of a string using the colon as a delimiter, this will work:

```
string = %q{Test Data: Before the Data : "The War"}.partition(': ').pop
#=> "Before the Data : \"The War\""
```

String methods aren't inherently better or worse than [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html) or [MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/MatchData.html) methods, but they are frequently faster in the general case. More importantly, #partition is a different way of looking at the problem, and gives you a different set of methods to manipulate the results.

Comment: I did a benchmark of all the answers here out of fun and yours was the fastest one :D

Answer (score 1):

With string `[]` operator:

```
'Test Data: Before the Data : "The War"'[/[^:]*:(.*)/,1]
# => " Before the Data : \"The War\""
```

Doc is [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

The regex captures everything after the first colon. For extra security, I used a negative class matching anything but a colon `[^:]` before the colon.

Comment: @sawa why suppressing the irb prompt showing it's a real world output and not a supposed output ?

Comment: You should only write real output after `#=>`. Don't write a supposed output in the first place. Irb prompt makes it harder to read. And more importantly, code is primarily meant to run when written on a file. You can use irb to check, but that should be done in the backstage.

Comment: @Sawa ??? I don't get the point, I do prefer answers with real world 'screenshot' than a modified version. Moreover I'm quite used to makes HERE links to doc uppercase for reader attention, in lowercase most of people miss them, specially here with the low contrast colors choosen ...

Comment: Making words upcase outstands too much and it is ugly. There is enough color difference to tell that it is a link.

Comment: @Sewa You're propably not color blind, light blue on white is near the black, stressing it with uppercase letter helps understanding its a link and is an usual way of pointing to docs when the link is on a short word.

Comment: Indeed for the `[^:]` I forgot a repetition operator after it. Corrected.

Comment: I don't think having `[^:]*` or not would make any difference.

Comment: As said, it is unnecessary, specially with no start anchor.  I may have used `:(.*)` as the regex with the same result. It was just to give some clues to OP as the question sounds a restrictive exemple (I may be wrong here).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the strings before the first `:`

```
'Test Data: Before the Data : "The War" '.sub(/^[^:]*:/, "")
# => " Before the Data : \"The War\" "
```

Try this if you don't want the leading spaces.

```
'Test Data: Before the Data : "The War" '.sub(/^[^:]*:\s*/, "")
# => "Before the Data : \"The War\" "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Test Data: Before the Data : "The War"'
.split(": ", 2).last
#=> "Before the Data : \"The War\""
```

Comment: FWIW I upvoted as its the better solution in this context, answered with regex per OP tags only.

Comment: @Tensibai Okay. Sorry. And thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, but I still find your editing of answers quite rude and very opiniated, specially without even explaining it in the edit comment... but nevermind.

Comment: The primary motivation for my edit was that your answer included obvious grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Well, as english is not my native tongue I won't discuss a lot about it ;) the comma was intentionnal but could be bad, ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = 'Test Data: Before the Data : "The War"'.split(':',2)
print a[1..a.length]
#=> Before the Data : "The War"
```

String#split takes a second argument, the limit.

Answer (score -1):

Just kidding (solution not based on regexps at all):

```
s='Test Data: Before the Data : "The War"'

s.split(':')[1..-1].join(':').strip
# => "Before the Data : \"The War\""
```